# Display date in chinese in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nslocale

How to display current date in Chinese. I receive date in English language but I need to display it in Chinese in iphone.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and post your code!

Comment: you should post some code whatever you have tried so far. and you will get more answers from community.. hope you got me

Answer (score -1):

Get the number of the date,and replace the English word with Chinese...

Comment: can we not use iphone default date controls. I am trying to search for it as there is NSChineseCalendar so I thought may be we can do it with default date controls.